# Where is the clang <built-in> header file?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, internals

I was digging around in some C internals, and I found the following line from clang's `stddef.h` (located in `/usr/lib/llvm-11/lib/clang/11.0.0/include/`):

```c
typedef __WCHAR_TYPE__ wchar_t;
```

This is different from what I found in gcc's `stddef.h` (located in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.0.1/include/`):

```c
#ifndef __WCHAR_TYPE__    
#define __WCHAR_TYPE__ int    
#endif    
#ifndef __cplusplus    
typedef __WCHAR_TYPE__ wchar_t;    
#endif
```

In gcc's `stddef.h`, `__WCHAR_TYPE__` is clearly defined as an `int`, but in clang's `stddef.h` there was no mention of `__WCHAR_TYPE__` anywhere except for that one line. So, I decided to define the macro myself in order to find out where the macro was defined. I compiled the following file with clang:

```c
#define __WCHAR_TYPE__ x
```

And, I got the following warning:

```
file.c:1:9: warning: '__WCHAR_TYPE__' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
#define __WCHAR_TYPE__ x
        ^
<built-in>:85:9: note: previous definition is here
#define __WCHAR_TYPE__ int
```

It would seem that there's some sort of "built-in" header that defines the `__WCHAR_TYPE__` macro, and that header would appear to be an actual file, judging by the fact that a line number was provided. However, I recursively grepped for `#define __WCHAR_TYPE__ int` in `/usr` and I couldn't find anything outside of gcc's header files. So, my question is, is this "built-in" header file an actual file, and if so, where can I find it?

Comment: have you tried your IDE's "Go to definition"?

Comment: @bolov I feel like that wouldn't work in this particular case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not an actual file; clang has a number of predefined macros built in.

You can see all these macros by doing `clang -dM -E foo.c` where `foo.c` is any file (it can even be empty).  Among the list I saw

```
#define __WCHAR_TYPE__ int
```

In the clang source, this is all done in [`clang/lib/Frontend/InitPreprocessor.cpp`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/118b057f1268d1789e40ffceb214e73772df04f4/clang/lib/Frontend/InitPreprocessor.cpp#L812).

gcc actually has it as well (run `gcc -dM -E foo.c`; `clang` and `gcc` mostly support the same command-line options).  The `#define` in `<stddef.h>` is probably just there as a backup.

Comment: Wow, that's very strange. Thanks for the insightful information!